# Creating a Slide-Up Menu

Tags: c#, unity, gui, menu

How can I create a menu that slides up while "un-fading" as illustrated in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15Ix_qlXG-g) video?

As you can see in the video, the menu also falls down a bit in the end which gives it a realistic feel. I really have no idea on how to approach this, and searching the web did not help either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can animate just about anything in Unity. Fade effects are generally just the animation of the UI item's alpha color.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/animate-anything

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/changing-a-new-ui-images-alpha-value.289755/